# How to move two folder back

Tags: c#, path, directory

I have file in my application on root directory.

When I'm using below code:

```
string startupPat = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

It's taking also ...\bin\Debug\

How to move avoid this?

Comment: what do you mean by avoiding `\bin\Debug\` ?=!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working code:

```
string test= File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrent‌​Directory(), "..\\..\\test.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`\bin\Debug` is the default folder your program will be compiled into. If you run your program from Visual Studio this will most likely be the current directory. Anyway, when you copy the program to another folder, the `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` should return that folder.

For your file you have to set *copy to output directory* to *always* in the properties in order to copy the file to where your program will be.

For all files that live in the same directory as your program does you do noth need any paths, you can just use the relative file names

```
var textReadFromFile = File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");
```

Comment: how to put correct path in that case?
File.ReadAllText(startupPath + "myfile.txt");

Comment: @4est you are missing the connectory backslash use `Path.Combine(startupPath, "myfile.txt")`

Comment: In that case you won't need any path. If `myfile.txt` resides in the same directory as your program does, relative file names will default to this directory.

Comment: You can just use `File.ReadAllText("myfile.txt");` - Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: now working: var filetxt = Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..\\..\\myfile.txt");

Comment: Did you set the *copy to output directory* property of the file?

Comment: my code:
string test= File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..\\..\\test.txt"));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153023/discussion-between-paul-kertscher-and-4est).